# JS spawn I/O without closing it?

Tags: python, node.js, performance, terminal

I am currently working on a little server for my RPI3, to convert youtube videos to audio.
However, I have a problem :
My server is written in **JavaScript**, and my yt-algo (extracting, converting) is in **Python**. Each time I download a video, I have to do it with `exec` or `spawn`, and in it run some python script. But this process is not optimized at all, bc the computer has to load Python **everytime** a new video is downloaded...
SO
Is there a way to open a Python Shell (`python` in the terminal), let it open (it's in the ram for as long as the node process is open), and send some instructions (in Python) to it ?
For example, from the terminal:

```
$ python
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import youtube_downloader.py as ytd
>>> ytd.download_audio()
>>> ytd.convert_audio()
```

would become, in JS:

```
const python = spawn("python");
python.on("start", () => {
   python.do("import youtube_downloader.py");
   python.do("download_audio()");
   // etc...
});
```

But I've searched for two hours, and I can't find anything about it...
Thanks :)
Kyros

Comment: You could design a python server that you start up once and it just sits waiting for commands to work on and doesn't exit when done.  It's probably simplest to just make it an http server so you can just send it an http request when desired, but you could also send it data over stdio if you want or several other interprocess communication methods.

Comment: @jfriend00 , u should write it as an answer, cuz it's a good solution. thx a lot ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could design a python server that you start up once and it just sits waiting for commands to work on and doesn't exit when done. It's probably simplest to just make it an http server so you can just send it an http request when desired, but you could also send it data over stdio if you want or several other interprocess communication methods.